# Include Facebook Javascript SDK In WordPress

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to include the Facebook JavaScript SDK inside my wordpress custom theme. I'm able to do it in a standard MVC app or PHP website, but with wordpress I'm not sure how to proceed.

Usually a script is loaded using the `enqueue` function. I want to add it directly on the `<head>` tag of my **header.php** file, but I'm not sure if this will work. I've read FB documentation, and they suggest to use a plugin, but if I don't want to use a plugin what's the best approach?

Comment: "using a plugin" is a way a customise wordpress to add a functionnality. that doesn't meant that you have to use a existing plugin. edit your question to add more details about what you want to do with this SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the `header.php` file of your theme. In that case, it's as easy as just enqueueing the script by appending this function to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function enqueue_facebook_javascript_sdk(): void {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'facebook-javascript-sdk-initializer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/your/initializer.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'facebook-javascript-sdk', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', array(), null );
    return;
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_facebook_javascript_sdk' );
```

The first JavaScript file should contain your version of [the initializer from the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart#loading), containing your `appId`.

In addition, the script requires the `async` and `defer` attributes. To add these, we insert a second function into `functions.php`:

```
function add_async_attribute( string $tag, string $handle ): string {

    if ( 'facebook-javascript-sdk' !== $handle ) {
        return $tag;
    }

    return str_replace( ' src', ' async defer src', $tag );
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'add_async_attribute', 10, 2 );
```

Please let me know if this works for you.